# ifelse with multiple logic tests of the same variable

Tags: r, if-statement

Say I have a vector of first names, like this:

```
names <- c("Bernice", "Dianna", "Philip", "Laurie",
           "Rochelle", "Arturo", "Enrique", "Sarah",
           "Darryl", "Arthur")
```

I would like to create another vector with the gender of each name. This is how I do it:

```
ifelse(names == "Bernice" | names == "Dianna" | names == "Laurie"
       | names == "Rochelle" | names == "Sarah", "Feminine",
       ifelse(names == "Philip" | names == "Arturo" | names == "Enrique"
              | names == "Darryl" | names == "Arthur", "Masculine", NA))
```

However, I bet there's a better alternative to using `|names == ""` for each logic test (my real case ended up with 250 lines just for this variable).

So far, I've tried this (this works in `grep`, but apparently not here):

```
ifelse(names == "Bernice|Dianna|Laurie|Rochelle|Sarah", "Feminine",
       ifelse(names == "Philip|Arturo|Enrique|Darryl|Arthur", "Masculine", NA))
```

As well as this:

```
ifelse(names == "Bernice" | "Dianna" | "Laurie" | "Rochelle" | "Sarah",
       "Feminine",
       ifelse(names == "Philip" | "Arturo" | "Enrique" | "Darryl" | "Arthur", 
              "Masculine", NA))
```

But none seem to work.

I run into this problem a lot when treating dataframes (having to use `ifelse` with multiple logic tests of the same variable), and i have checked out some questions on SO regarding multiple ifelse, but can't seem to find anything I could use.

Comment: You're looking for `%in%` I think.

Comment: Have a look at the dev version of the [qdap package's](https://github.com/trinker/qdap) `name2sex` function.  Your problem may as easy as `names2sex(names)` which yields: `[1] F F M F F M M F M M`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983708/square-brackets-multiple-columns-r/18000604#18000604) might be useful.

Comment: @joran, would you mind elaborating further as an answer?

Comment: @TylerRinker, sounds like a plan. Will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
> girls <- c("Bernice", "Diana", "Laurie", "Rochelle", "Sarah")
> ifelse(names %in% girls, "Feminine", "Masculine")
 [1] "Feminine"  "Masculine" "Masculine" "Feminine"  "Feminine"  "Masculine" "Masculine"
 [8] "Feminine"  "Masculine" "Masculine"
```